# Insert a page break if the height of a div does not fit in print media?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically creating elements on a web page which I want to print. I want a page break if the element can't fit in the rest of the A4 size paper.
Example is this question: [Force an element to take exactly half of available height in print media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626299/force-an-element-to-take-exactly-half-of-available-height-in-print-media)

In the picture, A broken element is appearing on first page, which should actually go on the second page.

How can I force a page break if the element does not fit in this page. 
**What I tried: **

I tried to use css `page-break`after` property, with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".row").each(function(){

    if($(this).height()>$(document).height()/2){
      $(this).after('<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>');
    }
  });

});
```

But it does not work.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahuew49m/)

Comment: Have you tried [page-break-inside](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp)?

Comment: yes, does not work

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your fiddle that you have applied page breaks only after a few rows. The problem with your jQuery code is that, the `$(document).height()` will return a huge value compared to each row. In your case, document height = 3861 while each row is only 537. Hence 537 is never greater than 3861/2. Revisit the exact condition you need to apply the page break. I tried window.height instead and it works.

***Note***: You can only see the difference in print preview

EDIT:
Could you remove all the page break div's you manually added and try the below script.
What I tried is to capture the previous element height and then calculate if he page break is necessary. 
For this purpose, I have kept a maxHeight of the document to be 1024 considering how much an A4 sheet can take up. Feel free to adjust the maxHeight according to your paper size.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var prevRowHeight = 0;
        $(".row").each(function(){
            // console.log($(this).height());
            var maxHeight = 1024;
            var eachRowHeight = $(this).height();
            if((prevRowHeight + eachRowHeight) > maxHeight){
                $(this).before('<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>');
                console.log("add page break before");
            }
            prevRowHeight = $(this).height();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Do let us know if it does or doesn't.

Comment: document and window both return the same height. :)

Comment: True that 3861 is too much so What I tried was I just divided the document height by the number of pages.  I got 840. If the height of the div, is greater than half of 840, i.e. 420, It should go to next page.   But now the problem is that Every div is going to next page because the height of this div accounts to 577 which is greater than 420................ I wonder How come two divs fit in **some** pages when the height is same for all pages (840).

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer was good but there is a bug. You must need total_height. Please Check this I think this code help you. I use this code for a hospital management project for printing system. Thank you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var prevRowHeight = 0;
        var total_height = 0;
        jQuery(".row").each(function(){

            // console.log($(this).height());
            var maxHeight = 1000;
            var eachRowHeight = jQuery(this).height();
            total_height += prevRowHeight + eachRowHeight;
            alert('now : '+total_height +' , Was: '+ prevRowHeight);
            if(total_height > maxHeight){
                jQuery(this).before('<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>');
                console.log("add page break before");
                now_height = 0;
            }
            prevRowHeight = jQuery(this).height();
        });

    });
```